# Bound and Operator Norm of this linear mapping example

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

For an exercise, I need to investigate whether some linear mappings are bounded and determine the operator norm. I seem to be stuck on this particular one :

$T_3 : l^p(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow l^p(\mathbb{N})$ , $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \{c_n x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ , $p \in [1, \infty]$ , $c = \{c_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$

My approach towards boundedness would be :

$\left\| T_3(x) \right\|_p = \left\| c_1 \cdot x_1 + c_2 \cdot x_2 + ... \right\|_p = \left\| \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} c_i \cdot x_i \right\|_p \leq \left\| c \right\|_p \cdot \left\| x \right\|_p$

Now, boundedness can be shown if $\left\| c \right\|_p \leq C$. However, my confusion is to exactly show/investigate this since we also have that $c = \{c_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$, meaning I am not sure how to apply the $\left\| . \right\|_p$ to $c$ as defined in this case.

Help is much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\displaylines{\|T_3(x)\|_p^p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_nx_n|^p \\ \le \sup_n|c_n|^p\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p \\ =(\sup_n|c_n|)^p\|x\|_p^p}$$ Therefore $$\|T_3(x)\|_p\le \|c\|_\infty \|x\|_p$$ and $\|T_3\|\le \|c\|_\infty.$ Let $\delta_n$ denote the standard basis in $\ell^p.$ Then $$\|T_3(\delta_n)\|_p=\|c_n\delta_n\|_p=|c_n|\,\|\delta_n\|_p$$ Hence $|T_3\|\ge |c_n|.$ As $n$ is arbitrary we obtain
$$|T_3\|\ge \|c\|_\infty$$

Comment: Ah, great! So it was not really hard. I have understood your way. And by showing that  $\left\| T_3 \right\| \leq \left\| c  \right\|_{\infty}$ and  $\left\| T_3 \right\| \geq \left\| c  \right\|_{\infty}$, we have that  $\left\| T_3 \right\| = \left\| c  \right\|_{\infty}$. However, can you please elaborate on the last part, i.e. why $\left\| T_3 \right\| \geq \left\| c  \right\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: I have extended the explanation. Should be more transparent now.